# Java framework/tool for simple distributed computing problem

Tags: java, frameworks, parallel-processing, distributed

We generate pdf files with data regarding monthly financial balance of tens of thousands of clients. At it's peak (100.000 files at the end of year), the process may take as long as 5 days to complete using distribute the load between 5 servers. The distribution of workload is a manual process (eg. server 1 generates pdf for clients 1 to 20.000, server 2 from 20.001 to 40.000, and so on).

We use Java, so we would like to use a Java tool or framework in a fashion similar to [BOINC](http://boinc.berkeley.edu/) (BOINC is not coded in Java), which would allow us to have:

- a server automatically distributing data and code to workers, and managing them
- workers (plain dual core desktops using free (or not so) cpu cycles) receiving code sent by server and executing it using the data as input, giving some status feedback, and finally doing something with the output, eg. sending pdf generated files to network storage.

For now, we don't want to try heavyweight all-powerful toolkits such as Globus Toolkit.

¿Do you know any java framework/tools suitable to our needs? Open source would be nice, but we don't discard commercial solutions.

Comment: Why do you prefer other java-framework? BOINC is not coded in Java is the only reason?

Comment: BOINC would be the chosen tool because It woud suit our needs. Java code can be executed from Boinc client, but the native BOINC interface is written in C. That's our main reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many:

- http://www.jppf.org/
- https://jxta.dev.java.net/
- https://java.net/projects/cajo/pages/Home
- http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Java/Class_Libraries/Networking_and_Distributed_Computing/

Google is your best friend here.

Comment: Thanks. In fact I  had googled a little and found GridGain and jppf, but nothing quite like boinc. Cajo looks interesting.

Comment: A bit late... but +1 for using the dmoz directory.

Comment: All of these links except for jppf are, as of now, dead.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Hazelcast distributed executor service](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.4/manual/html-single/hazelcast-documentation.html#executor-service). It uses Java's standard ExecutorService API.

Answer (score 2):

- http://hadoop.apache.org/
- http://www.gridgain.com/
- http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/coherence/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Google says there is a Java port of BOINC here: http://boincoid.sf.net

It's mostly targeting about android :-/ but apparently all but the GUI can run on a regular VM.

Comment: Nice. In fact it says there will be a Java Port and an Android Port soon.

Answer (score 0):

Another one you can look at is [Terracotta](http://www.terracotta.org/).